# What is $E[X]$ and $\text{Var}(X)$ if $X$ follows $Pois(T^2)$ and $T$ follows Exponential distribution

Tags: random-variable, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

I'm new to this community.
I have problem in finding expected value and variance of R.V.s that are composed of other R.V.s following other distributions.
Suppose $X \sim Pois(T^2)$ where $T \sim Exp(\lambda)$ $(\lambda>0)$. How can I calculate $E[X]$ and $\text{Var}(X)$?

---

I assume it will be quite easy to find $\text{Var}(X)$ if there is a way to calculate $E(X)$ using the following formula,
$$
\text{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E[X]=E[E[X|T]]$

$Var[X]=E(var(X|T)) + var(E(X|T))$